# jQuery "replaceWith" doesn't work inside "on"

Tags: jquery, click, replacewith

Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/z1ot7c2g/12/

```
var DomTreeCopyWithRows = $(".crops #tiles").clone(true, true);

    $(document).on("click", ".mod", function(){
        //if there is any other opened, restore original DOM order
        $('.crops #tiles').replaceWith(DomTreeCopyWithRows);

        $this = $(this);
        //detect which tile's clicked
        var clickedModClass = "." + $this.children(".content").attr("class").split(' ')[1];

        //move content to after the nearest row wrapper
        $(clickedModClass).closest(".row").after($(clickedModClass));
        //open
        $(clickedModClass).addClass("opened").show();
        $(clickedModClass).animate({
            height : $(clickedModClass)[0].scrollHeight
        },"slow");

         return false;
     });
```

I have responsive tiled grid with on-click expandable panels that open underneath a row of modules. The row depending on screen is either 1, 2, 3 or possibly more modules inside .row wrapper added on the fly.
 On click the content of clicked module is taken out of .mod and attached straight after the .row.
 There is only one meant to be opened at a time.
Problem: when you click for the second time, in order to close the already opened other module's content and to put it back inside of that other .mod I use `$('.crops #tiles').replaceWith(DomTreeCopyWithRows)` to put in previously saved DOM structure.

Problem:

```
$('.crops #tiles').replaceWith(DomTreeCopyWithRows) doesn't work.
```

I still get multiple opened containers.

DOM replacement worked on **`$(".crops #tiles").click`** , but I wouldn't be able to keep my click event attachment after DOM replacement happened.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: could you explain how it's meant to work from the user's perspective pls?

Comment: Tsar, when user click a box it opens a container with content underneath the row of the boxes where the clicked on is. When the next box is clicked, the first one closes automatically, the next one produces a drop down container that appears straight underneath the row where the box is.

Comment: T.J. apologies if I'm not very clear, it's my first post. In Fiddler when you click each box only one dropdown is meant to appear, so there is only one opened at a time. On clicking every other box, the dropdown that was already opened closes automatically.
The issue is here: DomTreeCopyWithRows isn't put in on click.
var DomTreeCopyWithRows = $(".crops #tiles").clone();

            $(document).on("click", ".mod", function(){
            //if there is any other opened, restore original DOM order
            $('.crops #tiles').replaceWith(DomTreeCopyWithRows);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that once you've done the `replaceWith` **once**, the nodes referenced by your `DomTreeCopyWithRows` are the ones in the DOM, and so they're the ones that get modified. And since you do that every time there's a click, the first time puts your copy in the DOM, and there it stays, being modified by the subsequent code.

The minimal-changes fix is to clone again when adding:

```
$('.crops #tiles').replaceWith(DomTreeCopyWithRows.clone(true, true));
// -----------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1ot7c2g/13/)